# Cell checkmark odd one out goes blue while others change UIColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `UITableView` is currently using a custom green color for the checkmark accessory, I set this by simply using `[[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"]];`. This works just fine, except there is always one cell, that repeats(b/c of cell reuse), that stays the default blue. I have no idea why this is happening, if anyone knows what you can do to prevent this "odd man out" problem I'm having, please share. Here's my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    #define CHECK_NULL_STRING(str) ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || !str)?@"":str

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inviteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"]];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    if (cell == nil) {cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }

    BOOL isSearching = tableView != self.tableView;
    NSArray *arrayToUse = (isSearching ? searchResults : contactsObjects);
    id p = arrayToUse[indexPath.row];

    NSString *fName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByFirstName));
    NSString *lName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByLastName));
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", CHECK_NULL_STRING(fName), CHECK_NULL_STRING(lName)];

    BOOL showCheckmark = [[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    if (showCheckmark == YES)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = YES, and stateArray is %@",stateArray[indexPath.row]);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = NO, and stateArray is %@",stateArray[indexPath.row]);
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    id object = contactsObjects[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [stateArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] atIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedObjects addObject:object];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [stateArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] atIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedObjects removeObject:object];
    }

    //slow-motion selection animation.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You are setting an appearance selector multiple times. These only need to be called once to set a particular attribute. You should probably do this in your AppDelegate or somewhere else that gets called on app startup.

This is the line in question:

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"]];
```

Once you fix this, the issue you're posting about will actually be fixed. The reason this is occurring is because the appearance selector is only used on newly initialized objects.
`- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` not only dequeues a cell but also initializes one if there is nothing to dequeue. What this means is that exactly one cell is created without the tintColor you want before your appearance selector is set.

1. As I mentioned before, the method you are calling actually creates a cell if needed. This means that all of this:

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
   }

   if (cell == nil) {cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }

well never get called, so you might as well get rid of it.

Comment: Ok so I deleted the unnecessary methods that back up the cell creation. So with the tint method, I just need to move it to AppDelegate? And would moving it right above the `deque` method work?

Comment: Oh wow haha. moving the appearance code right above the `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:` actually worked. Thank you so much @Dima

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong when you get a new cell. You set some of the cell attributes before you check if you have a cell. Do the check for 'nil', get a new cell if necessary, then mess about with your cell.

Comment: this is not the reason for the issue. The Dequeue method he is using guarantees a valid cell. See my answer for more details.

Comment: The nil checks did prove to be unnecessary, +1.

Comment: I missed the 'forIndexPath' on the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method (must learn to scroll across to see all the code).